# Why Sometimes i am getting ANR while getting storage path or creating directory or making sever call in android

Tags: android, performance, android-anr-dialog

My App throws only very few time these **ANR's**. Just i need to solve **ANR** in my app.

Sometimes my app getting **ANR** while getting `storagepath`. 
I am using following code to get storage path:

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Appname/cache/name"+1+".txt");
```

here `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` throws **ANR**.

Same as i am getting ANR when i am creating directory using the following code

```
file.mkdirs();
```

this code throws **ANR** sometimes.

Comment: 1- are you having this problem on every device? or it happens only on a particular one? 2- could you please post more code? you might be causing the ANR somewhere else

Comment: Hello lelloman, thank you for your reply. My app is in Google play i found these ANRs only from playstore console ANR block.. There are details about this ANR place i am sure this code only making ANR only few times and device

Comment: although it would be better to perform file operation not on the UI thread, it seems a bit unlikely that those 2 lines of code you posted could be the cause of the ANRs